# Evaluating $\int \frac{\cos(x)-1}x \, dx= \int \frac{\cos(x)\cdot 1}x -\frac 1 x \,dx$ under an infinite series form (Taylor)

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I would please need help on an indefinite integral : 
$$\int \frac{\cos(x)-1} x \, dx= \int \left(\frac{\cos(x)\cdot 1} x -\frac 1 x \right) \, dx$$
I need to transform it under an infinite series form.

I tried separating $\cos(x)$ of $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{-1}{x}$, and then I multiplied the MacLaurin series of $\cos(x)$ by $\frac{1}{x}$.

I got 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!} +\ln |x| + C$$

However, I know the waited solution is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{2n\cdot(2n)!}$$

I don't know how to reach to this form, could you please help me with it ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Please verify my edits and please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \ldots
       = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!},
$$
hence
$$
\frac{\cos x -1}{x}
 = -\frac{x}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{4!} \pm \ldots
 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k-1}}{(2k)!},
$$
and integrating we get
$$
\int \frac{\cos x -1}{x} dx
 = \int \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k-1}}{(2k)!}
 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \int \frac{x^{2k-1}}{(2k)!}
 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{2k(2k)!}
$$
which is not quite in the form you are expecting.

Comment: isn't $cos x=1-x^2/2+x^4/4!-  -+-+'

Comment: Thank you a lot, I'm sorry I wrote down the wrong solution, I appreciate your help ! However, I don't quite understand how you came up with the series you came up to with cos(x)-1/x

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima corrected, forgot...

Comment: @Kat write out the series for the cosine with a couple of terms. Subtracting one just removes the leading 1. Then, dividing by $x$ reduces the exponents of the terms by one each.

Comment: Ohhh thank you I understand now !